# rspec 3 allow message error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3

in rspec 2, i can do this.

> let(:user_1) { create :user_1) # factoryGirl Object
>
> User.stub(:where).and_return(user_1)
>
> user_1.stub(:where).and_return(user_1)

but in rspec 3, it occurs a failure.

> let(:user_1) { create :user_1) # factoryGirl Object
>
> allow(User).to receive(:where).and_return(user_1)
>
> allow(user_1).to receive(:where).and_return(user_1) # this line occurs a failure

the error message is,

> Failure/Error: allow(product_1).to receive(:where).and_return(product_1)
>
> ```
>    #<User ..... object description.... >
> ```
>
> does not implement: where

what should i do to pass this example?

### **---------- update question ----------**

in controller,

```
operators = Admin

if !params[:name].blank?
  operators = operators.where('adm_name like ?', '%' + params[:name] + '%')
end

if !params[:login_id].blank?
  operators = operators.where('adm_login_id like ?', '%' + params[:login_id] + '%')
end

if params[:status] != "all"
  operators = operators.where('status=?', params[:status])
end

if !params[:id_check].blank?
  operators = operators.where('adm_login_id = ?', params[:id_check])
end
```

in spec,

```
let(:admin) { create :admin }

before do
  allow(Admin).to receive(:where).and_return(admin)
  allow(admin).to receive(:where).and_return(admin)
end

it 'should be success' do
  get :search, params
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

then failure message is,

```
Failure/Error: allow(admin).to receive(:where).and_return(admin)
   #<Admin ... object description ...> does not implement: where
```

first, i removed this statement in `before` block,

```
allow(admin).to receive(:where).and_return(admin)
```

then i got a failure message,

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `first' for #<Admin:0x007f99d2e166d0>
```

so i tried this(returns array),

```
allow(Admin).to receive(:where).and_return([admin])
```

then i got a failure message,

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007f9a67313e28>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to stub the `where` method on a model instance?  `where` is a class method, not an instance method.  `user = User.first; user.where()` should raise a NoMethodError. Maybe try just commenting out that line?

Comment: you mean, `user_1.stub(:where)` is weird? but in rspec2, that codes work well. `user_1.stub(:where).and_return(user_1)` returns `user_1`

Comment: Rspec2 may not complain about it, but that stub was probably never used any way.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so is there any way to stubing on statement like `users = users.where('name = ?', params[name])`? i dont care whether 'where' method works well or not, i just want to get a fake object like FactoryGirl or double(mock object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stub `User.where` so that it returns an array of users, use:

```
expect(User).to receive(:where).and_return([user_1])
```

And then remove the line where you are getting the failure.

**Update**

The problem is that you are trying to stub the same thing twice in a row. The first line is almost right, and the second is just plain wrong. You need to do it once correctly and remove the other line. Change your code to look like the following:

```
let(:admin) { create :admin }

before do
  allow(Admin).to receive(:where).and_return([admin])
end

it 'should be success' do
  get :search, params
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

Comment: thanks for answering. but stubing on User(class) is not a problem. my problem is, stubing on fake object like factory girl. `allow(User).to receive(:where).and_return([user_1])` doesnt matter. but `allow(user_1).to receive(:where).and_return([user_1])` statement occurs failure.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code you are trying to stub.

Comment: then i got `NoMethodError:
   undefined method 'where' for #<Array:0x007f9a67313e28>` error because of this statement `operators = operators.where('adm_login_id like ?', '%' + params[:login_id] + '%')` in controller